# Parallelized Web Crawler

Tags: beginner, go, concurrency, url

Exercise is here:

https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/10

Prompt:

> In this exercise you'll use Go's concurrency features to parallelize a web crawler.
>
> Modify the Crawl function to fetch URLs in parallel without fetching the same URL twice.
>
> Hint: you can keep a cache of the URLs that have been fetched on a map, but maps alone are not safe for concurrent use!

Code:

````
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

//I didn't touch this interface
type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

type urlCache struct {
    mu sync.Mutex
    wg sync.WaitGroup
    urls map[string]int
}

func (u *urlCache) add(url string) bool {
    u.mu.Lock()
    defer u.mu.Unlock()
    if _, exists := u.urls[url]; !exists {
        u.urls[url] = 1
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, cache *urlCache) {
    defer cache.wg.Done()
    
    if depth <= 0 || !cache.add(url) {
        return
    }
    
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s - %q\n", url, body)
    
    for _, u := range urls {
        cache.wg.Add(1)
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, cache)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    cache := &urlCache{urls: make(map[string]int)}
    cache.wg.Add(1)
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, cache)
    cache.wg.Wait()
    
}

// I didn't touch anything below this line.

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "https://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
```
````